# Inverse of polynomial in $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})[X]/(x^N-1)$ where $m$ is a prime power.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

*I want to check if my answer to the following question is sound.*

Note: The operation ($\star$) denotes polynomial multiplication in a quotient polynomial ring, and $p$ is a prime.

Suppose $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^N-1)$ such that there exist $F(x)$ and $f(x)\star F(x)\equiv 1 (\bmod p^i)$ for some $i\geq 1$. 
 Prove that the polynomial $G(x) = F(x)\star (2-f(x)\star F(x))$ satisfies $f(x)\star G(x)\equiv 1 (\bmod p^{2i})$

*Source: Hoffstein-Pipher-Silverman, an introduction to mathematical cryptography. Problem 7.27, page 460*

**Following is my attempt:**
$f(x)\star G(x) = 2\star f(x)\star F(x) - f(x)^2\star F(x)^2$. Hence, $f(x)\star G(x) (\bmod p^i) \equiv 2-1 (\bmod p^i) \equiv 1 (\bmod p^i)$.
Since $\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}/p^{2i}\mathbb{Z}$, it follows that $f(x)\star G(x) \equiv 1 (\bmod p^{2i})$

In the above proof, I am using the assumption that $\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}/p^{2i}\mathbb{Z}$. However, I am not sure of that fact. At least, by looking at the element of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$ as *integer*, it follows that $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$.

Any help/hint will be welcomed. Also, if this is a duplicated question or the wrong StackExchange, I apologize in advance. A quick search on this stack exchange did not produce a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously $\equiv 1\bmod p^i$ doesn't imply $\equiv 1 \bmod p^{2i}$.

Write $fF = 1+p^i H$ so that

$$fG = 2fF - (fF)^2= 2+2p^i H- 1-p^{2i} H^2-2p^i H$$